# Tensorflow: Custom Loss Function Not Providing Gradients

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I am trying to define a custom loss function in tensorflow that penalizes false positives and false negatives based on the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695913/custom-loss-function-in-keras-to-penalize-false-negatives#comment121807718_55787295). I have to modify the code that calculates specificity and recall quite a bit because I have a multiclass classification problem and the problem from the post is only binary classification. I am training with my images stored in `ImageDataGenerator` objects if it matters.

What the loss function does is as follows.

1. Convert the logits in `y_pred` and one-hot encoded classes in `y_true` to a sparse numerical vector (eg. [0, 2, 1, 1]) for each batch
2. Instantiate counters for the True Positives, True Negatives, False Positives, and False Negatives (TPx, TNx, FPx, FNx - x being either 0, 1, or 2 depending on the class). The gargantuan   `if` and `elif` statements basically count each spot in the confusion matrix, because a 3x3 confusion matrix is significantly more complicated than a 2x2 confusion matrix. It simply adds up the metric per class (TP_g, TN_g, FP_g, FN_g) to get the total metric.
3. Converts the added metrics to a tensorflow tensor (I stole that part from the aforementioned post)
4. Calculates specificity and recall, then subtracts a weighted sum from `1.0` to return the total loss for the batch.

Here is the loss function that I've defined:

```
def myLossFcn(y_true, y_pred, recall_weight, spec_weight):
    #benign ==0
    #hyperplastic ==1
    #neoplastic ==2
    
    y_true = np.argmax(y_true, axis=1)
    y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    
    y_true = tensorflow.cast(y_true, tensorflow.float32)
    y_pred = tensorflow.cast(y_pred, tensorflow.float32)
    
    print('y_true:', y_true)
    print('y_pred:', y_pred)
    
    #true positives for all classes
    TP0 = 0
    TP1 = 0
    TP2 = 0
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        if y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 0:
            TP0 += 1 #benign true positive
        elif y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 1:
            TP1 += 1 #hyperplastic true positive
        elif y_true[i] == 2 and y_pred[i] ==2: #neoplastic true positive
            TP2 += 1
    TP_g = TP0 + TP1 + TP2 #num true positives total (per batch) 
        
    #true negatives for all classes
    TN0 = 0
    TN1 = 0
    TN2 = 0
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        if (y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 1)  or (y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 2) or (y_true[i] == 2 and y_pred[i] == 1) or (y_true[i] == 2 and y_pred[i] == 2):
            TN0 +=1
        elif (y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 0) or (y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 2) or (y_true[i] == 2 and y_pred[i] == 0) or (y_true[i] == 2 and y_pred[i] == 2):
            TN1 +=1
        elif (y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 0) or (y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 1) or (y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 0) or (y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 1):
            TN2 +=1
    TN_g = TN0 + TN1 + TN2
    
    #false positives for all classes
    FP0 = 0
    FP1 = 0
    FP2 = 0
    
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        if (y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 1) or (y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 2):
            FP0 +=1
        elif (y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 0) or (y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 2):
            FP1 +=1
        elif (y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 2) or (y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 2):
            FP2 +=1
    FP_g = FP0 + FP1 + FP2
    
    #false negatives for all classes
    FN0 = 0
    FN1 = 0
    FN2 = 0
    
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        if (y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 1) or (y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 2):
            FN0 +=1
        elif (y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 0) or (y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 2):
            FN1 += 1
        elif (y_true[i] == 0 and y_pred[i] == 1) or (y_true[i] == 1 and y_pred[i] == 2):
            FN2 +=1
    FN_g = FN0 + FN1 + FN2
    
    #Converted as Keras Tensors    
    TP_g = K.sum(K.variable(TP_g))
    TN_g = K.sum(K.variable(TN_g))
    FP_g = K.sum(K.variable(FP_g))
    FN_g = K.sum(K.variable(FN_g))
    
    print(TP_g)
    print(TN_g)
    print(FP_g)
    print(FN_g)
    
    specificity = TN_g / (TN_g + FP_g + K.epsilon())
    recall = TP_g / (TP_g + FN_g + K.epsilon())
    print('spec:', specificity)
    print('recall:', recall)
    
    loss = 1.0 - (recall_weight*recall + spec_weight*specificity)
    print('loss:', loss)
    
    return tensorflow.constant(loss)
```

Following the previous post, I instantiate a function wrapper to pass in the weights for specificity and recall, then start training:

```
def custom_loss(recall_weight, spec_weight):
    def recall_spec_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return myLossFcn(y_true, y_pred, recall_weight, spec_weight)
    
    return recall_spec_loss

model = tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights=None,
                                                    input_shape=(100,100,1),
                                                    pooling=max,
                                                    classes=3)
loss = custom_loss(recall_weight=0.9, spec_weight=0.1)
model.compile(optimizer=hyperparameters['optimizer'],
          loss=loss,
          metrics=['accuracy', tensorflow.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()],
          run_eagerly=True)

history = model.fit(train_set,
                epochs=50,
                callbacks=[model_checkpoint],
                validation_data=val_set,
                verbose=2)
```

When I run my code, I get an error back

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: [FOR BREVITY I WILL NOT COPY+PASTE ALL OF THE GRADIENT NAMES THAT IT LISTED]

I will also post the output that I receive and the traceback up to that error message:

```
Found 625 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 376 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 252 images belonging to 3 classes.
Epoch 1/50
y_true: tf.Tensor([0. 2. 1. 0.], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)
y_pred: tf.Tensor([0. 0. 0. 0.], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(2.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
spec: tf.Tensor(0.8, shape=(), dtype=float32)
recall: tf.Tensor(0.6666667, shape=(), dtype=float32)
loss: tf.Tensor(0.32, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/endo_git_v2/justin_method.py", line 253, in <module>
    verbose=2)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1178, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 850, in train_function
    return step_function(self, iterator)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 840, in step_function
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 1285, in run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 2833, in call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3608, in _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 597, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 833, in run_step
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 794, in train_step
    self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 530, in minimize
    return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 630, in apply_gradients
    grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/utils.py", line 76, in filter_empty_gradients
    ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
```

I have been looking online quite a bit to no avail. I have ensured that all my variables are tensors to the best of my ability as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292992/tensorflow-2-custom-loss-no-gradients-provided-for-any-variable-error) and looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63874265/keras-custom-loss-function-error-no-gradients-provided) but I don't really understand what the solution meant by:

> Keep in mind that the python function you write (custom_loss) is called to generate and compile a C function. The compiled function is what is called during training. When you python custom_loss function is called, the arguments are tensor objects that don't have data attached to them. The `K.eval` call will fail, as will the `K.shape` call

I am also not even sure that the second post is relevant, but it is all I could find on the internet. I am hoping that the solution is as simple as I forgot to do something really obvious, or change something that is easy, but for the life of me I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

I have updated my loss function so that all the intermediate values are tensorflow Tensors of dtype float32 and am receiving the same errors:

```
def myLossFcn(y_true, y_pred, recall_weight, spec_weight):
    #benign ==0
    #hyperplastic ==1
    #neoplastic ==2

    print('y_true:', y_true)
    print('y_pred:', y_pred)

    tp = tensorflow.keras.metrics.TruePositives()
    tp.update_state(y_pred, y_true)
    
    TP_g = tp.result()

    tn = tensorflow.metrics.TrueNegatives()
    tn.update_state(y_pred, y_true)
    
    TN_g = tn.result()

    fp = tensorflow.keras.metrics.FalsePositives()
    fp.update_state(y_pred, y_true)
    
    FP_g = fp.result()

    fn = tensorflow.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()
    fn.update_state(y_pred, y_true)
    
    FN_g= fn.result()
    
    print(TP_g)
    print(TN_g)
    print(FP_g)
    print(FN_g)    
    
    #Converted as Keras Tensors
    TP_g = K.sum(K.variable(TP_g))
    TN_g = K.sum(K.variable(TN_g))
    FP_g = K.sum(K.variable(FP_g))
    FN_g = K.sum(K.variable(FN_g))
    
    print(TP_g)
    print(TN_g)
    print(FP_g)
    print(FN_g)
    
    specificity = TN_g / (TN_g + FP_g + K.epsilon())
    recall = TP_g / (TP_g + FN_g + K.epsilon())
    print('spec:', specificity)
    print('recall:', recall)
    
    loss = 1.0 - (recall_weight*recall + spec_weight*specificity)
    print('loss:', loss)
    
    return tensorflow.constant(loss) #probably not a tensorflow scalar atm
```

I am printing the metrics twice to see if the `K.sum(K.variable(**METRIC**))` affects anything.

Here is the output:

```
tf.Tensor(8.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(0.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(0.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(8.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
spec: tf.Tensor(0.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
recall: tf.Tensor(0.33333334, shape=(), dtype=float32)
loss: tf.Tensor(0.7, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/endo_git_v2/justin_method.py", line 282, in <module>
    verbose=2)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1178, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 850, in train_function
    return step_function(self, iterator)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 840, in step_function
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 1285, in run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 2833, in call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3608, in _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 597, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 833, in run_step
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 794, in train_step
    self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 530, in minimize
    return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 630, in apply_gradients
    grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
  File "/home/d/dsussman/dsherman/.conda/envs/myNewEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/utils.py", line 76, in filter_empty_gradients
    ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61894755/adding-a-if-condition-in-a-custom-loss-mse-function  the problem is the if and for statement

Comment: There are multiple issues here, first is that losses have to be implemented using tensorflow, not numpy, and computing TPs, FPs, TNs, etc, is not differentiable, this is a mathematical problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will try that and update this post

Answer (score 1):

Its because the loss function you have defined does not support converging into an answer and its derivative has discontinuity. i.e when you convert the error into zeros and ones.
Gradient descent needs to converge into an answer gradually and discrete loss function does not help with that.

Comment: how can I fix that? by only using `keras.backend` functions or something else?